# Strange 'SIGSEGV' performance about signal() function

Tags: c, signals, segmentation-fault

I have 3 example applets to describe my confusion here.

***First,a classic segmentation fault's program is like this:***

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{       
    int *p=NULL;
    *p=0; //here will cause a SIGSEGV signal
}
```

When I run the applet above,the terminal will show

```
# ./a.out 
Segmentation fault
```

***Next,I add a signal() function in the applet,then it will look like this:***

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void handler(int s)
{   
    if(s==SIGSEGV)
        printf("It's SIGSEGV!\n");
    exit(1);
}
main()
{   
    int *p=NULL;
    signal(SIGSEGV,handler);
    *p=0;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the applet above,the terminal will show

```
# ./a.out 
It's SIGSEGV!
```

***At last,I delete the NULL string in the applet,it will run SUCCESSFULLY!!:***

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void handler(int s)
{   
    if(s==SIGSEGV)
        printf("It's SIGSEGV!\n");
    exit(1);
}
main()
{   
    int *p; //There is no more 'NULL' here
    signal(SIGSEGV,handler);
    *p=0;
    printf("The value of p is %d\n",*p);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is

```
# ./a.out 
The value of p is 0
```

***Why?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dereferencing uninitalized pointer is undefined behaviour. Anything can happen. Program is broken, and you cannot reason with it.